# Compare 2 columns in Excel and show matching values iff in DIFFERENT rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, compare, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel file with 2 columns. My purpose is to highlight the cell values if there are matching values (duplicate) in the 2 columns. Here, the major point to note is that, the cells should be highlighted only if the duplicate values belong to different rows of COLUMN 1 and COLUMN 2. i.e.,  `[COL1, ROW1]` value is equal to `[COL2, ROW3]`.

So, highlight the cell if any values in **COLUMN 1** is available in **COLUMN 2** but with different rows only.

[image]

Comment: Select the entire range you want to evaluate and in the conditional formatting apply format for duplicate values

Comment: @Naresh But that will show duplicates only if the values are of the same row, right?

Comment: no it should show all the values in the selection as you apply the format to entire selection at once.

Comment: Okay. One more change needed. I will update the question. It shouldn't show duplicates if it belongs to the same row.

Comment: what are the chances that a number will appear more than twice?.. Is it likely that same number can appear twice in the same row and then more than once in next rows?

Comment: Yes, your second statement stands correct! It can occur in the same row as a duplicate (which I don't want to highlight) and then repeat the value in the second column multiple times. Highlighting values in both the columns would make it difficult, probably we can highlight the  values in COLUMN 1 if there is one or more matches in COLUMN 2 but not in the same row. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

See the image below, You can add one more rule to the conditional formatting and stop it if true ("A") but it will highlight if the same value("A") appears again somewhere in the selection.

[image]

Comment: Please check.. rows in the formula are not fixed by $

Comment: Your comment : probably we can highlight the values in COLUMN 1 if there is one or more matches in COLUMN 2 but not in the same row. Hope it is clear now. .... if the same number does not repeat in the first column then you need to apply the formula conditional formatting only to the second column

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can interpret the question.

(1) You want to check if there is no match in the current row, but there is a match somewhere else.

For the the first column, you want to check if the number next to it is not the same but there is a match somewhere else in the second column, so use custom formula:

```
=AND(B1<>A1,COUNTIF(B:B,A1))
```

Similarly for the second column:

```
=AND(A1<>B1,COUNTIF(A:A,B1))
```

[image]

(2) You want to check if there is a match somwhere else *even if there is a match in the current row*

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)-(A1=B1)>0
```

and

```
=countif(A:A,B1)-(A1=B1)>0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT to check the conditions you want:

> *highlight the cell if any values in COLUMN 1 is available in COLUMN 2 but with different rows only.*

I made a fake dataset like this:

[image]

As you can see, only cells with values `1` and `3` meet the condition, because value `2` it's duplicated, but in same row only, so it should not be highlighted.

My Conditional Formatting rule is based in this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$4:$B$8=A4);--(ROW($B$4:$B$8)<>ROW(A4)))>0`

This is how it works:

1. `--($B$4:$B$8=A4)` will return an array of 1 and 0 based on which values are the same than `A4`
2. `--(ROW($B$4:$B$8)<>ROW(A4))` will return an array of 1 and 0 based on what cells got **different* row number than cell `A4`
3. `SUMPRODUCT` will multiply and sum up both arrays, and we'll obtain a final array of 1 and 0. **Each 1 means there is a cell with same value but on a different row**. We sum up all 1 and 0 obtained.
4. We compare result from previous step with `>0`. IF true, means there is 1 or more cells that got same value but on a different row, so we highlight.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** In case you want to highlight values of column 2 too, you can use almost same formula and CF rule, just changing column references:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$4:$A$8=B4);--(ROW($A$4:$A$8)<>ROW(B4)))>0`

[image]